# Need User to login and be directed to localhost:3000/users (rails app)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-4

I need users to login and be directed to localhost:3000/users. I've got a bit lost after going through online tutorials so i'd be grateful for any help.

**routes.rb**

```
  resources :users

  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

  root  'static_pages#home'

  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new',            via: 'get'
  match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new',         via: 'get'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy',     via: 'delete'

  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help',    via: 'get'
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about',   via: 'get'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact', via: 'get'
```

**sessions_controller.rb**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_back_or user
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

Comment: match is deprecated you can use `get '/signup', to: 'users#new'`, any kind of redirection would normally be handled in the `SessionsController` (assuming that from the `resources :sessions`.  Would you care to share the controller?

Comment: @muttonlamb hi. I've added the Sessions Controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def create
  user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
  if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
    sign_in user
    redirect_back_or users_url # <--- Changes
  else
    flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Comment: I did think 'xxx_url' played a role. I'm getting my head around Rails slowly but surely! Thanks for the help : )

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following it will redirect to users index page after login.

```
match 'users' => 'users#index', via: :get, as: :user_root
```

Then try this

**sessions_controller.rb**

```
def create
   user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
   if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
     sign_in user
     redirect_to user_root_path
   else
     flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
     render 'new'
   end
end
```

Comment: Do i need to remove a line and replace it with this?